# C#. Работа с бд. Ado.net и отдельные библиотеки.

Tags: c#, ado.net, sql

Возможно вопрос слишком прост, но не могу понять.

Есть в c# DataSet, DbConnection, DataReader, DataAdapter.
Есть примеры подключения с помощью них к бд и отправке запросов и получения результатов.

Мне нужно работать с PostgreSql, для этого есть отдельная библиотека.

Вопрос: Можно использовать стандартные средства, перечисленные выше?

Если да, то в чем плюсы и минусы использования стандартных средств от отдельной библиотеки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всегда можно взять тот же odbc или ole, но отдельная библиотека, особенно созданная самим разработчиком СУБД может выполнять те или иные операции, ну, скажем, правильнее. Может присутствовать обработка исключений, с которыми можно столкнуться при использовании стандартных подходов и т.д.

Минус нестандартной библиотеки как минимум один - необходимость распространения :-)

Comment: Спасибо большое! Прояснили ситуацию:)